# В приложении Android не работает доступ к файлам, почему?

Tags: android

Приложение-браузер (https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/450506/)
На сайте доступ к выбору файлов работает, а вот в приложении нет.
В приложении при нажатии кнопки выбора файла, кнопка нажимается, а менеджер файлов не появляется.

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Возможно, дело в версии ОС. Попробуйте запустить на версии ниже 9.

Comment: попробую,  я пробую android 11, хотелось бы что бы на актуальных версиях все работало.

Comment: Это подтверждает мою догадку. Засим повторюсь - попробуйте на более старой версии ОС запустить. В эмуляторе например. Если будет работать - надо ковырять в сторону новых правил доступа к файлам на Андроиде

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло 9 и 8.1

Comment: В таком случае - не знаю в чём дело(

Comment: Ну ладно, если узнаю напишу тут.